# F# HttpClient timeout issues

Tags: linux, .net-core, f#, httpclient

I have used two ways of creating a HttpClient, both written slightly different but both result in a http post request being sent. But I am encountering some strange behavior when working with the first method.

## 1

```
let HttpPost clientTimeoutInMilliseconds (content:StringContent, serviceEndpoint:string) =
    let httpClient = new HttpClient()
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
    httpClient.Timeout <- new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, clientTimeoutInMilliseconds)
    httpClient.PostAsync(serviceEndpoint, content).Result
```

This function results in many timeouts occurring, very slow response times (regularly 3, 4, 5, ... seconds) and high thread usage before eventually causing threads to be exhausted and the application to stop. From our logs we can see initially thread usage is normal but after a short period of time every message which the application processes is assigned to a new thread. This will happen under both light and heavy work loads.

## Exception

[image: Exception]

## 2

```
let HttpClientCreate timeoutInMilliseconds () =
    let httpClient = new HttpClient()
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
    httpClient.Timeout <- new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, timeoutInMilliseconds)
    httpClient

let HttpPost clientTimeoutInMilliseconds (content:StringContent, serviceEndpoint:string) =
    let httpClientCreate' = clientTimeoutInMilliseconds |> HttpClientCreate
    httpClientCreate'().PostAsync(serviceEndpoint, content).Result
```

After switching to the code above the timeouts disappear, the response times and thread usage return to normal. I have ran this code over a weekend and have not encountered any issues.

The only difference in the two versions is the partial application being used in the second method. I didn't think this would be an issue, but maybe someone can clear this up?

The clientTimeoutInMilliseconds is set to 10000

Running on .net core version is 2.2.101

Linux version is 18.04.3

Comment: The accepted wisdom is that you should always reuse HttpClients, not create one for each request.  Creating a lot of HttpClients (even if you dispose of them) causes resource exhaustion issues.  I think that is the cause of your issue here.